# I am having this issue with jquery with an indication that a function is not defined meanwhile I defined the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having this issue with jquery. one of a number of functions in my jquery returns **"Uncaught ReferenceError: curLocZip is not defined"** when I call it in another function.

**Here is the function definition:**

```
function curLocZip(){
        curZipCode = "";
        if (navigator.geolocation) { //Checks if browser supports geolocation
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) { 
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                var  latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)

                geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[0]) {
                            for (i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[0] == 'postal_code'){
                                    curZipCode = results[0].address_components[i].short_name;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                    }
                });             
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
}
```

I called the it in another function like so:

```
curLocZip();
```

I am not sure why I am get the error that indicates that curLocZip() is not defined.

Comment: Where in the code is `curLocZip` defined? Where is it being called?

Comment: a) where and when do you define the function b) where and when do you call it?

Comment: I defined _curloczip()_ (fna curLocZip) in `$(document).ready(function() {...});` and I called it with the same (stated). Through setting a default value in the _curloczip()_ for a global variable and then calling the function, I noticed that the function actually returns a value when called, just that it returns before the API processing with it is completed. I am now looking for how to have the API processing completes before the function returns when called.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that you are defining it on page load and calling it before it is defined. You must do the call to function only after the page is loaded, so you might want to start your processing on an `onLoad` callback.

Comment: The function call seem to be working just fine, I've noticed after printing out in the console. The issue seem to be that function returns before the API processing is completed. So, when I remove a the Google Maps API calls and just return a variable with a set data, the function call seem to work just fine. Like so: `function curloczip(){
  curZipCode = "38104";

  return curZipCode;
}`